# How do I overload the [] operator in C#

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, indexer

I would like to add an operator to a class.  I currently have a `GetValue()` method that I would like to replace with an `[]` operator.

```
class A
{
    private List<int> values = new List<int>();

    public int GetValue(int index) => values[index];
}
```

Answer (score 865, accepted):

```
public int this[int key]
{
    get => GetValue(key);
    set => SetValue(key, value);
}
```

Comment: Why is it that every time I need to implement an index operator, I have to look it up?  And each time I end up on this answer... wish I could vote it up multiple times :)

Comment: This is so super awesome. Can it be done in an interface? ``interface ICache
   {
      object this[string key] { get; set; }
   }`` **Edit:** [Yes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586625/how-to-define-indexer-behaviour-to-an-interface)

Comment: dont know why they chose to omit the word 'operator' in this declaration - thats the mistake I always make!  Nice answer

Comment: Michael: You should probably be using generics: `interface ICache<TContent> { TContent this[string key] { get; set; } }`.

Comment: You can also use multi dimensional array `public int this[int x, int y]`

Answer (score 69):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

**[Indexers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx(v=VS.100).aspx)**

```
class SampleCollection<T>
{
    private T[] arr = new T[100];
    public T this[int i]
    {
        get => arr[i];
        set => arr[i] = value;
    }
}

// This class shows how client code uses the indexer
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SampleCollection<string> stringCollection = 
            new SampleCollection<string>();
        stringCollection[0] = "Hello, World";
        System.Console.WriteLine(stringCollection[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 34):

The [] operator is called an indexer. You can provide indexers that take an integer, a string, or any other type you want to use as a key. The syntax is straightforward, following the same principles as property accessors.

For example, in your case where an `int` is the key or index:

```
public int this[int index]
{
    get => GetValue(index);
}
```

You can also add a set accessor so that the indexer becomes read and write rather than just read-only.

```
public int this[int index]
{
    get => GetValue(index);
    set => SetValue(index, value);
}
```

If you want to index using a different type, you just change the signature of the indexer.

```
public int this[string index]
...
```

Comment: And don't forget you can have any combination of types for multiple indexers....

Answer (score 12):

```
public int this[int index]
{
    get => values[index];
}
```