# Building an object with a [] interface ( not from ILIst) in c#

Tags: c#

I want to pass around some values in an array that will always be a known size.   I would like to define a class that represents this array of decimal values which could not be resized, would always have the same number of elements, and supports the [] array notation.

In c++ I could do an operator overloading for this - but I can't see how to do it in c#

To be clear - the use of the class would be something like:

```
MyValues values = new MyValues;
values[3] = 14;
values[7] = 10
```

....
And later

```
decimal aValue = values[2];
```

Suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with `decimal[]`?

Comment: You'll want to take a look at the index operator. See this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424669/how-do-i-overload-the-operator-in-c

Comment: you should avoid using decimal, it has poor performance

Comment: @Andrey - could you provide some detail?

Comment: @Mike: `Decimal` is implemented in software, so it will be slower than `double`, which is done by the FPU.  However, `decimal` is more precise.

Comment: @Slaks - Thank you. I do know that. I was only trying to get Andrey's reasoning in case it was something else. I probably should have noted the trade off in my comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to write an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx), like this:

```
public decimal this[int index] {
    get { return data[index]; }
    set { data[index] = value; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks

What I could not find documentation about what the indexer - just what I need

Comment: Then you should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.

Answer (score 5):

Use an indexer

```
public class MyValues {
    private readonly decimal[] numbers = new decimal[10];

    public decimal this[int index] {
        get { return numbers[index]; }
        set { numbers[index] = value; }
    }
}
```

You might want to add some bounds checking to provide better failiure messages. Also you  probably do not want to hard code the array size.

Comment: You don't need to add bounds checking - the array already does.

Comment: @SLaks - yes of course, but you might want to fail in a different way than the way the array will fail. The "Clearly" part is clearly too strong here.

Answer (score 3):

Using an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx), you could write a simple generic class like:

```
    public class FixedArray<T>
    {
        private T[] array;

        public int Length { get { return array.Length; } }

        public FixedArray (int size)
        {
            array = new T[size];
        }

        public T this[int index]
        {
            get { return array[index]; }
            set { array[index] = value; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

something like:

```
decimal this[int ind]
{
   get
   {
      return array[ind];
   }
   set
   {
      array[ind] = value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try ReadOnlyCollection class. Also be aware of the dangers of arrays, really good article [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx)