# How to define Indexer behaviour to an Interface?

Tags: c#, interface

Is it possible to add the indexer behaviour from an interface?

something like this :

```
interface IIndexable<T>
{
   T this[string index];
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. In fact, all you're missing is the getter/setter on your indexer. Just add it as follows:

```
interface IIndexable<T>
{
     T this[string index] {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 16):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkyhsw31.aspx):

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    // ...

    // Indexer declaration:
    string this[int index] { get; set; }
}
```

> Indexers can be declared on an interface (C# Reference). Accessors of
> interface indexers differ from the accessors of class indexers in the
> following ways:
>
> - Interface accessors do not use modifiers.
> - An interface accessor does not have a body.

Answer (score 3):

A bit more generic interface (taken from `IDictionary<,>`), would be:

```
interface IIndexable<TKey, TValue>
{
    TValue this[TKey key] { get; set; }
}
```

I only wonder why they didn't include it in mscorlib, so that IDictionary could implement it. It would've made sense.