# Generic Collections C#

Tags: c#, enumerator, generic-collections

I have implemented a generic custom collection class which only takes a Person type object.

While providing support for the Enumerator to iterate through the collection it shows an error

> *Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'CustomCollection.CustomCollection'*

Below is the code snippet for the class I created.

```
public class CustomCollection<T> : ICollection<T> where T : Person
{
    private IList<T> lst = null;

    public CustomCollection()
    {
        lst = new List<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        this.lst.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        this.lst.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        bool result = false;

        foreach (T obj in this.lst)
        {
            if (obj.Id.Equals(item.Id))
            {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this.lst.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        bool result = false;

        foreach (T obj in this.lst)
        {
            if (obj.Id.Equals(item.Id))
            {
                this.lst.Remove(item);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new PersonEnumerator<T>(this);
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
```

The Enumerator class as below:

```
public class PersonEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T> where T : Person
{
    private CustomCollection<T> collection = null;
    private int index;
    private T current;

    public PersonEnumerator(CustomCollection<T> collection)
    {
        this.collection = collection;
        this.index = -1;
        current = default(T);
    }

    public T Current
    {
        get { return this.current; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return this.Current; }
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (++this.index >= collection.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            this.current = collection[this.index];
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        this.index = -1;
        current = default(T);
    }
}
```

Person Class only contains FirstName, LastName & Id as properties in it.

Comment: Are you missing the indexers declaration in your custom collection class? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx

Comment: Have  a look at Operator Overloading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3hd7ste.aspx

Comment: Whoops. Wrong link. Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424669/how-do-i-overload-the-operator-in-c-sharp

Comment: Side note: `public bool Remove(T item)` implementation contains an *error*: you *can't modify* a collection (`this.lst` in your case) withing *foreach* loop

Comment: also noticed `IEnumerator.Current` is wrong inside `PersonEnumerator<T>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ICollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) doesn't implements an indexer. If you want to use indexing, you should implement [IList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) instead.

You can use `Linq` with `ICollection`:

```
var result = Items.ElementAt(index);
```

Or you can add your own indexer:

```
public T this[int i]
{
    return Items[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your code build, you need to add an [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx), to your `CustomCollection<T>` class, e.g.

```
public T this[int index]
{
    return lst [index];
}
```

Then you can say use `collection[n]` to get the n<sup>th</sup> element in the `MoveNext()` method.

---

**Or**

Instead of having your `PersonEnumerator<T>` class you could just expose `lst.GetEnumerator()` which returns an `IEnumerator<T>`, i.e.

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    return lst.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Unless you're planning on doing anything fancy with your enumerator, you might as well use the one for `lst`.