# Make your own array

Tags: c#

This might be a very basic question, but really don't know how to make it. I want to create the following:

```
public class MyArray
{
    List<KeyValuePair<int, object>> myList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, object>>();

    public void Set_Value(int index, object value)
    {
        myList = myList.Where(a => a.Key != index).ToList();
        myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, object>(index, value));
    }
    public object Get_Value(int index)
    {
        if (myList.Any(a => a.Key == index)) return myList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Key == index).Value;
        else return null;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyArray array = new MyArray();
        array[0] = "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

Make a array that i manipulate myself...

Comment: So what problem are you having with your array implementation?

Comment: Sorry it is a duplicate, i could not find it in google...

Comment: It's also worth noting that your implementation of this mechanism is *super* inefficient, in a lot of ways.

Comment: This is called the [indexed property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Now i'm curious, what would be the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an index operator to your class:

```
public object this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        if (myList.Any(a => a.Key == index)) return myList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Key == index).Value;
        else return null;
    }
    set
    {
        myList = myList.Where(a => a.Key != index).ToList();
        myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, object>(index, value));
    }
}
```

Note that you have several opportunities to improve your code; I just copy/pasted it to show the mechanics of the index operator.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is how you overload the indexer operator.

For that, see here:
[How do I overload the [] operator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424669/how-do-i-overload-the-operator-in-c-sharp)

However, I'd advise against recreating the wheel here. It's probably better to actually use an array or inherit from a collection class.

Comment: If you feel that a question is answered by another question you should flag/vote to close it as a duplicate, not post an answer with a link to the duplicate question.