# How to access the 2D array in my custom class directly

Tags: c#

I have class `ShapeMap` which contains 2D int array `shapeMap`.
in my main script I reference my class as `ShapeMap map` is there a way I can get value using `int value = map[x,y]`?

My `ShapeMap` class is

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class ShapeMap {

private int[,] shapeMap;

public ShapeMap(int width, int height, string seed, int randomFillPercent, int smoothAmount) {

    shapeMap = new int[width, height];

    RandomFillMap (randomFillPercent, seed);

    for (int i = 0; i < smoothAmount; i++) {

        Smooth ();

    }

}

private void RandomFillMap() {

}

private void Smooth() {

}

}
```

and my Main Script is

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MapGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

ShapeMap map;

public int width, height, fillPercent, smoothAmount;
public string seed;
public bool useRandomSeed;

private void Awake() {

    if (useRandomSeed) {

        seed = Time.time.ToString ();

    }

    map = new ShapeMap (width, height, seed, fillPercent, smoothAmount);

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            int value = map [x, y];

            if (value == 1) {

                // Do This

            } else {

                // Do That

            }

        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Can you show your codes?

Comment: What is the problem on `map.shapeMap[x, y]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I overload the \[\] operator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424669/how-do-i-overload-the-operator-in-c-sharp)

Comment: There is no technical problem with it however it is messy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is to modify your `ShapeMap` adding indexer:

```
public int this[int x, int y]
{
    get { return shapeMap[x, y]; }
    set { shapeMap[x, y] = value; }
}
```

[Try this online](http://rextester.com/WNMV19299)

---

More information about indexers you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/index)

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering how to do this and had no idea where to start looking for or what to call it, this is exactly what I wanted.